# How to design spring batch to avoid long queue of request and restart failed job

Tags: spring-batch

I am writing a project that will be generating reports. It would read all requests from a database by making a rest call, based on the type of request it will make a rest call to an endpoint, after getting the response it will save the response in an object and save it back to the database by making a call to an endpoint.

I am using spring-batch to handle the batch work. So far what I came up with is a single job (reader, processor, writer) that will do the whole things. I am not sure if this is the correct design considering

1. I do not want to queue up requests if some request is taking a long time to get a response back. [not sure yet]
2. I do not want to hold up saving response until all the responses are received. [using commit-internal will help]
3. If the job crashes for some reason, how can I restart the job [maybe using batch-admin will help but what are my other options]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using chunk oriented processing Reader, Processor and Writer get executed in order until Reader has nothing to return.
If you can read one item at a time, process it and send it back to the endpoint that handles the persistence this approach is handy.

If you must read ALL the information at once the reader will get a big collection with all items and pass it to processor. The processor will process all the items and send the result to the writer. You cannot send just a few to the writer so you would have to do the persistence directly from processor and that would be against the design.

So, as I understand this, you have two options:

1. Design a reader that can read one item at a time. Use the chunk oriented processing that you already started to read one item, process it and send it back for persistence. Have a look at how other readers are implemented (like JdbcCursorItemReader).
2. You create a tasklet that reads the whole collection of items process it and sends them back for processing. You can break this in different tasklets.

**commit-interval** only controls after how many items transaction is commited. So it will not help you as all the processing and persistence is done by calling rest services.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a design and I think it will work fine.

As for the questions that I asked, following are the answers:

1. Using asynchronous processors will help avoiding any queue.
   http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#asynchronous-processors
2. using commit-internal will solve it
3. This thread has the answer - [Spring batch :Restart a job and then start next job automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307908/spring-batch-restart-a-job-and-then-start-next-job-automatically)

Comment: As Cristian Sevescu maintained  commit-internal will not solve  the hold up of saving response until all the responses are received.