# Is there a way to auto-resume batch jobs in spring batch?

Tags: heroku, spring-batch

I am trying to run a spring batch job in Heroku dyno.  Let's say the job contains 2 steps.

If the Heroku dyno recycles (read as JVM shuts down) while step 2 is in progress, is there a way to start from step 2 the next time JVM comes up?

Comment: check this link, it might be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307908/spring-batch-restart-a-job-and-then-start-next-job-automatically